# Swapping 1994-95 Diamond back sport response components out

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, parts, shifter, diamondback

My Diamondback sports response is from roughly 1994-95, The Shimano STX shifters are completely done on it. I would like to not purchase a new bike seeing that nothing is wrong with this frame. Is there a new model of shimano shifters that would work? or any suggestions on swapping out all the components for this bike?

Comment: Do you care about originality at all?  If not pick up a pair of modern button shifters from your LBS.  Finding authentic and period original shifters on ebay might be your only original option.   Have you considered reconditioning the old shifters?

Comment: I'd think you're probably going to have to go online either way. I don't know any LBS in my town or neighboring towns that stocks 7 speed stuff all that much.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it runs a 3x7 Shimano mountain drivetrain. You can get new shifters such as the Shimano ST-EF51's (the 3x7 version; which are switchable between V-brakes and cantilevers -- see manual for details) or the SL-M310 (in the 7 speed version for the rear, triple for the front; add your own brake levers if yours are integrated with the appropriate cable pull). I'd probably opt for the SL-M310's personally -- I've had the ST-EF51's briefly and the quality left something to be desired.

Alternatively, you can buy the Microshift DS85-7 (grip shifts) or TS38-7 (trigger shifters) and add your own brakes. Or SRAM Attack! grip shifts.

If you're really cheap, just buy a set of thumb friction shifters. Any ones will do. These aren't indexed so you have to move them into the right position to shift based on feel.

I'd also suggest replacing the cables while you're at it.